# JAXB JSON JAR Runtime List reader not available

Tags: java, jaxb, intellij-idea, jersey

I have a small project created with IntelliJ IDEA, using Jersey. 
I already created the server part working just fine and hosted on a GAE server. 
I try to connect to it via a Jersey Client, and here comes the strange stuff. 
Everything works fine if I run my application from inside the IntelliJ IDEA. However, once I run the jar JSON support seems to be gone, however XML works. Any ideas?

I feel I need to mention that the jersey-json is packaged with the generated jar. 
Here it is the jar file in question. You'll need both the jar and the dll file, one near the other and just run it.

The Console Output (Error): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B42XvjSlpDCtTTdwQl9MSTBlQ0U

The JAR file I used (all dependencies extracted into it). Any JRE6 may run it. https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B42XvjSlpDCtTVNUQTQ4SXFCcDg

The DLL required for the JAR (although, it should work without this too): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B42XvjSlpDCtNXpabVk5RDkyRW8

And here's the source code on the github (public): https://github.com/gaborbernat/fs_viewer

Finally, I attach a picture with the settings of the artifact (JAR) generate rules. [image: The JAR artifact generation]

Thanks for your support, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-tests/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/impl/json/ListOfJAXBBeanTest.java?rev=5698

(your usecase can be extracted from there; the point is that you need to configure Jersey Client to be able to handle json by a) registering JAXBContextResolver or b) explicitly adding MessageBodyWriters (jackson))

And dont forget to use GenericEntity (as in linked test).